# Kubernetes 1.4 and weave-net: networking not working

Tags: networking, kubernetes, atomic, centos7, weave

I've used Kubeadm to bootstrap a cluster, and added weave-net with

`kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube`

and I have everything running, but I can't "see" any of the assigned IP's within the cluster.

So:

`[centos@atomic01 ~]$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP                NODE
default       hello-2533203682-b5usp                                1/1       Running   0          13m       10.42.0.0         atomic03
default       test-701078429-ely8s                                  1/1       Running   1          3h        10.40.0.1         atomic02
kube-system   dummy-2088944543-6i81l                                1/1       Running   0          5h        192.168.150.150   atomic01
kube-system   etcd-atomic01                                         1/1       Running   0          5h        192.168.150.150   atomic01
kube-system   kube-apiserver-atomic01                               1/1       Running   0          5h        192.168.150.150   atomic01
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-atomic01                      1/1       Running   0          5h        192.168.150.150   atomic01
kube-system   kube-discovery-982812725-c1kkw                        1/1       Running   0          5h        192.168.150.150   atomic01
kube-system   kube-dns-2247936740-nrszw                             3/3       Running   2          5h        10.32.0.2         atomic01
kube-system   kube-proxy-amd64-0y8ik                                1/1       Running   1          5h        192.168.150.152   atomic03
kube-system   kube-proxy-amd64-57y4o                                1/1       Running   0          5h        192.168.150.150   atomic01
kube-system   kube-proxy-amd64-mjpik                                1/1       Running   1          5h        192.168.150.151   atomic02
kube-system   kube-proxy-amd64-sh3ej                                1/1       Running   1          5h        192.168.150.153   atomic04
kube-system   kube-scheduler-atomic01                               1/1       Running   0          5h        192.168.150.150   atomic01
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-3095304083-xwuw8                 1/1       Running   1          2h        10.38.0.0         atomic04
kube-system   weave-net-edur9                                       2/2       Running   0          1m        192.168.150.151   atomic02
kube-system   weave-net-l9xp3                                       2/2       Running   0          1m        192.168.150.150   atomic01
kube-system   weave-net-sjpui                                       2/2       Running   0          1m        192.168.150.153   atomic04
kube-system   weave-net-xu7j5                                       2/2       Running   0          1m        192.168.150.152   atomic03`

I *should* be able to ping the other nodes, but

`[centos@atomic01 ~]$ kubectl exec test-701078429-ely8s -- ping 10.42.0.0                                                                                PING 10.42.0.0 (10.42.0.0) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                                                                        From 10.40.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable                                                                                                  From 10.40.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable                           From 10.40.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable`

Of course, this works:

`[centos@atomic01 ~]$ kubectl exec test-701078429-ely8s -- ping 192.168.150.150
PING 192.168.150.150 (192.168.150.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.150.150: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.484 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.150.150: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.448 ms`

I've run out of ideas, any clues on things to test or look out for would be much appreciated. [Running on Centos 7 Atomic VM's]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, does any of the test or hello Pods expose any ports? Can you access a port on the hello pod from the test pod?

Normally, I don't think ping should work (unless you have a Pod that processes icmp requests), so I actually don't think there's anything wrong here.

Just run a Pod (preferably from a Deployment) that exposes a port maybe 80 for simplicity, set `containerPort: 80` and you should be able to curl that Pod IP successfully. Also consider making a Service with a stable IP that loadbalances requests to matching Pods, as Pods might come and go.

Hope it helps!